# Install Ubuntu over Android

Tags: android, smartphone

I have that old Android smartphone I'm not using anymore and I'd like to install Ubuntu or a derivate on it. Is it possible to do that and, if so, how?

I found some tutorials about dual boot with Android and Ubuntu and virtual machines running Ubuntu in Android. Note that they're not what I'm looking for: I want to *overwrite* Android with Ubuntu, *not* to have both of them nor one inside the other.

Comment: just for my curiosity: is there a specific purpose to do that?

Comment: @Asqan Well, not really. I just have that old device I don't use anymore and I'd like to revive it in something useful - and I don't need a second Android smartphone.

Comment: Generally speaking, no. There is support for only a handful of devices, and it in not trivial to make it work on a new one, let alone any old phone. It is easy to find which phones are supported, but I'll post a link just in case. https://ubports.com/

Comment: @Ntakwetet What phone are you using? Please edit your question to include this